# Use Workflow to transfer or display item in new list

Tags: workflow

The goal is to have list items move or show up in a different list after a certain criteria is met, eg items in progress stay in Current app and are moved to the Past app after reaching the end date. 
Is this possible? I was told I could do it with a workflow, but my SharePoint "mentor" had to split before I could figure out what I was doing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  In SharePoint Designer, you should be able to build a custom workflow action that will create a new list item in the destination list with all of the appropriate metadata, based on the criteria you determine, and then delete the same list item in the source list.

Out of idle curiosity, any reason they have to be in two separate lists, rather than just presenting to the user two filtered list views? (i.e., one showing Current... apps? and one showing Past apps).

Not that there's anything wrong with the method you're asking about; given SharePoint's sometimes dodgy proclivities, I tend to air on the side of fewest possible moving parts for my solutions.